# javascript Object.create: setting properties "directly" vs setting properties declared in propertiesObject

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I apologize in advance if this has been asked elsewhere or if I have missed something important in the docs, well, but I need to ask this:

Let's say an object is being created without defining the respective properties

```
cons objA = Object.create({
  init(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
});
```

or an object is being created and the respective property has been declared in the properties object

```
const objB = Object.create({
  init(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
}, {
  text: {
    value: '',
    writable: true
  }
});
```

I understand that defining properties in the propertiesObject of Object.create helps defining and providing better contracts,

**but**

do these two scenarios vary in respect to the ***text*** property?

Comment: Is there a real use case? You should never pass an object literal to `Object.create` as the first argument, prototype objects are only useful if shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they vary - there is difference between **a** and **b** results

```js
const a = Object.create({
  init(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
});

const b = Object.create({
  init(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
}, {
  text: {
    value: '',
    writable: true
  }
});

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a))
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b))

a.init('a text'); 
b.init('b text'); 

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(a, 'text')) 
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(b, 'text'))
```

**a** returns:

```
{
      "value": "a text",
      "writable": true,
      "enumerable": true,
      "configurable": true
}
```

**b** returns:

```
{
      "value": "b text",
      "writable": true,
      "enumerable": false,
      "configurable": false
}
```

By default property is `enumerable` and `configurable` unless you define property by `Object.defineProperty` or `Object.create`. You can define them as you did with `writable`.

**Enumerable** works in certain object-property enumerations, such as the for..in.

**Configurable** means that you cannot use `Object.defineProperty` again on this property (there will be `Cannot redefine property: text` error).

Other than that - before you use `init()` - **a** object will have `undefined` `text` property (that is not enumerable, not configurable, writable) and object **b** will not have any property.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation!

Comment: @LongHike https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch3.md this is very nice source